# Ajax.ActionLink not calling controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, routes

I'm displaying a list of files and allowing the user to delete from the list. The delete button does an ajax call to the controller to run the 'Delete' action. However, the delete action is never called.I am getting the confirmation alert defined in AjaxOptions. For what it's worth, I had this working using the WebForms engine and just moved it to Razor. Also, this is the first time I've used Areas. If I call the Delete action directly, it works. Is this a routing issue?

Here's the code behind

```
  public EmptyResult Delete(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName.IsNullOrEmpty()) return null;
        var model = new Models.BenefitBookletModel();
        model.DeleteBooklet(fileName);
        return null;
    }
```

Here's the mark up

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("test", "Delete", new { fileName = item.FileName }, new AjaxOptions
                                                                                 {
Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete " + item.FileName + "?",
OnComplete = "function(){deleteComplete('" + item.jsReferenceableFileName + "')}",
HttpMethod = "DELETE",
OnFailure = "function(){alert('Could not delete file');}"
              }, new { @class = "DeleteButton" }
                                                                             )
```

Here is my RegisterRoutes

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute("SubscriberAll","subscriber/{id}",new { controller = "Subscriber", action = "ShowAll" },new { id = @"\d+" } );
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Routes from area registration

```
context.MapRoute("Marketing_default","Marketing/{controller}/{action}/{id}",new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Here is the markup generated

```
<a href="/Marketing/BenefitBooklet/Delete?fileName=MyFileName.pdf" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-failure="function(){alert('Could not delete file');}" data-ajax-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete MyFileName.pdf?" data-ajax-complete="function(){deleteComplete('MyFileName.pdf')}" data-ajax="true" class="DeleteButton"> </a>
```

Comment: Please add info from Global.asax where you register routes.

Comment: Is the Delete method in the same controller as what rendered the view? If not you will need to define the Controller using ActionLink(AjaxHelper, String, String, String, Object, AjaxOptions) overload.

Comment: Yes, both are in the same controller.

Comment: You mention 'Areas' in your question, but I don't see anything in the code/routes to indicate you are using areas. Is this Delete action in a different Area?

Comment: No. Everything in question is in the same area. Didn't know if there was anything I'm missing when using Areas. When it was working in the webforms view engine, I didn't use them and had no problem. Figured it was worth mentioning.

Comment: What about the routes in your area registration?

Comment: Have you used a tool like Firebug to verify if the DELETE request is being sent, and if it is being sent, confirm the address is correct?

Comment: @Zach Green - Added. Also, if I paste the href from the generated URL, it deletes the file as expected. It just doesn't work when clicking the Ajax.ActionLink.

Comment: As I can see from your markup, you have following `data-ajax-method="GET"`, but there should be something like this `data-ajax-method="DELETE"`. Did you see it?

Comment: And one more question. You wrote 'However, the delete action is never called.' What's happening when you're clicking on your link? Your UI is changing? If you set breakpoint in your `Delete` method, is it stopping on it?

Comment: @WarHog yes, you're right. The httpVerb was wrong. Updated. Still getting the same issue. I have a breakpoint on the controller action and it is never hit unless the url is ran directly. The UI doesn't do anything except the alert in the data-ajax-confirm param.

Comment: Sounds like you have a client side issue. Do you have the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js script included with jquery library in your layout file?

Comment: @ZachGreen - Yes, have that script included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify the function name as the value of the corresponding AjaxOptions property. Add `script` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnFailure(request, error) {
        alert('Could not delete file');
    }
    function OnComplete(request, error) {
        alert('Delete complete');
    }
</script>
```

in your view and change `OnFailure` and `OnComplete` in 'AjaxOptions':

```
OnFailure = "OnFailure"
OnComplete= "OnComplete"
```

Comment: That was the problem. The function() was causing issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the HttpMethod of the Action Link to be DELETE but you method probably only accepts GET. Try decorating it with the Delete action verb.

```
[HttpDelete]
public EmptyResult Delete(string fileName)
```

Comment: Tried HttpDelete and [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]. The controller action isn't called from the Ajax.ActionLink

Comment: It won't be working because you can't make a link to an action that will perform an HTTP delete, it's will be just a `fake delete` request I would expect you to get a 404 from clicking that link.

Comment: Do you have any JS errors on the page? You do have all the js files? Including jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js. You could try changing it to `[HttpPost]` and `HttpMethod = "POST"`.

Comment: Did that and checked Firebug. Shows error 'function statement requires a name > function(){alert('Could not delete file');}.' from the OnFailure AjaxOption...  Wierd.

Comment: Try `OnFailure = "(function(){alert('Could not delete file');}())"` or put your success and failure functions in a js file and just have `OnFailure = functionName`.